# Getting Multiple Matches with RegExp in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string like this:

```
`DateTime.now().setZone("America Blorp");`
```

This is my RegEx:

```
string.match(/DateTime\.(.*)[^)][(;]/)
```

How can I modify my RegEx so that I can get matches like this:

`DateTime.now` and `DateTime.now.setZone`.

I have tried to group matches like this

```
string.match(/DateTime\.(.*)([^)]*)([(;]*)/)
```

But I don't get the expected output. Can anyone please help me with this?

PS. I can only use `match` function, cannot use `matchAll`.

```js
const string = `DateTime.now().setZone("America Blorp");`

console.log(
  string.match(/DateTime\.(.*)[^)][(;]/)
)
```

Comment: You can use `/your_regex/g` for all match. 'g' = global match

Comment: Even when I use /g, I am not getting the desired output

Comment: Please provide example strings and expected output

Comment: Sorry for not pointing that out more clearly. The examples are the ones with `DateTime.now().setZone("America Blorp")` and the desired output should be `DateTime.now` and `DateTime.now.setZone`

Comment: `DateTime` doesn't looks to be javascript

Comment: It does not matter whether DateTime is javascript or not. DateTime functions as an input to the RegEx.

Comment: Sorry, it was not obvious to us that your string was just a string of code you wanted to parse in JS

Comment: @mplungjan that is okay, it was my fault; I didn't know how to make that obvious.

Comment: It is better now. I updated your question to make it obvious

Comment: But in the input string, you have `DateTime.now().setZone("America Blorp");`, which has `()` after now, but in your second desired output, it has no `()`: `DateTime.now.setZone`

Comment: This line seems wrong: `const string = \`DateTime.now().setZone("America Blorp");\``
This is not substituting. And even if you don't want to substitute, the string `'DateTime.now.setZone'` does not appear in the above string literally. And you need to use global flag if you want to use the string match function to get all matches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could match the format using 2 capture groups and concat the groups.

```
\b(DateTime\.now)\(\)(\.[^.()]+)\([^()]*\);
```

The pattern matches:

- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial match
- `(DateTime\.now)` Capture **group 1**, match `DateTime.now`
- `\(\)` Match `()`
- `(\.[^.()]+)` Capture **group 2**, match `.` and 1+ times any char except `.` or `(` and `)`
- `\([^()]*\);` Match from `(` till `)` and `;`

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Qg8Vsy/1).

```js
const regex = /\b(DateTime\.now)\(\)(\.[^.()]+)\([^()]*\);/;
const str = `DateTime.now().setZone("America Blorp");`;
const match = str.match(regex);
if (match) {
  console.log(match[1] + match[2]);
}
```